# "Runtime is not ready for debugging." Bug or am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hey guys I have been trying to fix this with no luck.

I am currently making a project in react-native, while running a simulator on my Mac OS.

I was coding the app just fine until I hit a point where I have to render some tags conditionally in my "app.js" .

This was just BEFORE the bug and THIS WORKED FINE:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';

import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Header, Button } from './components/common';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    loggedIn: null
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.state);

    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyB4YTQAkin5epZ4nCl8kJSNhQdBn9c8tbY',
      authDomain: 'auth-79bfa.firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://auth-79bfa.firebaseio.com',
      projectId: 'auth-79bfa',
      storageBucket: 'auth-79bfa.appspot.com',
      messagingSenderId: '1089451858009'
    });

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
        <Header headerText={'Authentication'} />
        <LoginForm />
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = {
  viewContainer: {
    height: '100%'
  }
};

export default App;
```

After this I added a helper function to conditionally render some JSX.
Here you can see the same Class with the renderContent() function added to it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';

import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Header, Button } from './components/common';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    loggedIn: null
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.state);

    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyB4YTQAkin5epZ4nCl8kJSNhQdBn9c8tbY',
      authDomain: 'auth-79bfa.firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://auth-79bfa.firebaseio.com',
      projectId: 'auth-79bfa',
      storageBucket: 'auth-79bfa.appspot.com',
      messagingSenderId: '1089451858009'
    });

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
      }
    });
  }

  renderContent() {
    if (this.state.loggedIn) {
      return (
        <Button buttonText='Log Out' />
      );
    } else if (this.state.loggedIn === null) {
      return (
        <Text> Loading... </Text>
      );
    } else if (!this.state.loggedIn) {
      return (
        <LoginForm />
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
        <Header headerText={'Authentication'} />
        {this.renderContent()}
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = {
  viewContainer: {
    height: '100%'
  }
};

export default App;
```

Just by adding this helper function the whole app breaks!! I launch the app and I actually get to see the 'Loading...' text until firebase responds and then the app just crashes. It just exits to the home screen or gives me the infamous red screen with the following error:

```
Runtime is not ready for debugging.
 - Make sure Packager server is running.
- Make sure the JavaScript Debugger is running and not paused on a breakpoint or exception and try reloading again.
```

This is really slowing me down and I hope any of you can help me!

These are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^4.1.3",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.46.1"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Timeout inside your helper function. Maybe the helper function is already checking the contents of your state even though firebase haven't finished setting up your loggedIn state yet. If it runs then try to make sure that your helper functions waits for your firebase function to finish before it fires.

Comment: But react re-renders itself once the state changes. That is actually the main point of react.